# Minitest not working

Tags: ruby, minitest

I have simple ruby app that parses a string and counts the number of Xs and Os, and returns true if there is an equal number, otherwise false.

I want to know why my test isn't working.

When I run the test, the app gets called, and the test runs, but there are 0 runs, 0 assertion...etc. Why?

The app:

```
class Calc

  def xo(str)
    ex = 0
    oh = 0
    for i in (0...str.length)
      if str[i] == "x" || str[i] == "X"
        ex += 1
      elsif str[i] == "o" || str[i] == "O"
        oh += 1
      else
      end
    end
    if ex == oh
      puts "equal" 
      return true
    else
      puts "not equal"
      return false
    end
  end
end

Calc.new.xo("xoxoo")
```

The test:

```
require_relative "task"
require "minitest/autorun"

class Test < MiniTest::Test

  def zeetest
    @calc = Calc.new
    assert_equal( true, @calc.xo("xoxo"))
  end

end
```

Comment: Pretty sure minitest requires that all tests begin with "test_", so you'd need to rename it to "test_zeetest"

Comment: As a coding style recommendation, indent your code correctly. It'll help readability and maintenance, for us and for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
require_relative "task"
require "minitest/autorun"

class TestCalc < MiniTest::Test

  def setup
    @calc = Calc.new
  end

  def test_xo
    assert_equal( true, @calc.xo("xoxo"))
  end

end
```